# Saving 2 copies of PDF template, 2nd file corrupt - iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF template file for 60 labels per page.  My goal was to make copies of the template as needed, fill in the form data and then merge the files into a single PDF (or provide links to individual files...either works)

The problem is that the 2nd PDF copy comes out corrupt regardless of date.

The workflow is user selects a date.  The lunch orders for that day are gathered into a generic list that in turn is used to fill in the form fields on the template.  At 60, the file is saved as a temp file and a new copy of the template is used for the next 60 names, etc...

09/23/2013 through 09/25 have data.  On the 25th there are only 38 orders, so this works as intended.  On 09/24/2013 there are over 60 orders, the first page works, but the 2nd page is corrupt.

```
    private List<string> CreateLabels(DateTime orderDate)
{

    // create file name to save
    string fName = ConvertDateToStringName(orderDate) + ".pdf"; // example 09242013.pdf

    // to hold Temp File Names
    List<string> tempFNames = new List<string>(); 

    // Get path to template/save directory
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/admin/labels/");
    string pdfPath = path + "8195a.pdf"; // template file

    // Get the students and their lunch orders
    List<StudentLabel> labels = DalStudentLabel.GetStudentLabels(orderDate);


    // Get number of template pages needed
    decimal recCount = Convert.ToDecimal(labels.Count);
    decimal pages = Decimal.Divide(recCount, 60);
    int pagesNeeded = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(pages));


    // Make the temp names
    for (int c = 0; c < pagesNeeded; c++)
    {
        tempFNames.Add(c.ToString() + fName); //just prepend a digit to the date string
    }

    //Create copies of the empty templates
    foreach (string tName in tempFNames)
    {
        try
        { File.Delete(path + tName); }
        catch { }

        File.Copy(pdfPath, path + tName);
    }

    // we know we need X pages and there is 60 per page
    int x = 0;

    // foreach page needed
    for (int pCount = 0; pCount < pagesNeeded; pCount++)
    {
        // Make a new page
        PdfReader newReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);

        // pCount.ToString replicates temp names
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path + pCount.ToString() + fName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(newReader, stream); 

            var form = stamper.AcroFields;
            var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

            StudentLabel lbl = null;

            string lblInfo = "";

            // fill in acro fields with lunch data
            foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
            {
                try
                {
                    lbl = labels[x];
                }
                catch 
                { 
                    break; 
                } // if we're out of labels, then we're done

                lblInfo = lbl.StudentName + "\n";
                lblInfo += lbl.Teacher + "\n";
                lblInfo += lbl.MenuItem;

                form.SetField(fieldKey, lblInfo);

                x++;

                if (x % 60 == 0)  // reached 60, time for new page
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            newReader.Close();

            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }        
    }

    return tempFNames;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code: why don't you allow stamper to close the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you pre-allocating your files? My guess is that's your problem. You're binding a `PdfStamper` to a `PdfReader` for input and an exact copy of the same pdf to a `FileStream` object for output. The `PdfStamper` will generate your output file for you, you don't need to help it. You're trying to append new data to an existing file and I'm not quite sure what happens in that case (as I've never actually seen anyone do it.)

So drop your whole `File.Copy` pre-allocation and change your `FileStream` declaration to:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path + pCount.ToString() + fName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
```

You'll obviously also need to adjust how your return array gets populated, too.

Comment: Well, looks like it was the pre allocation of the files that was somehow causing the issue.  After removing the File.Copy line to create copies of the template and using your suggested "using (FileStream...", it works like a charm.